# R Finding times between events and admissions, within patients

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a series of admissions for patients (dataframe 'admissions' below) and a series of events (2nd dataframe called 'events').
I am interested in whether events occurred within 5 days after an admission. Obviously matches have to be made within patient ID ('id').

In real life, the admissions data frame contains >500k admissions on 100k pts. One patient might have multiple admissions, and multiple events. Not all patients will have an event.

```
admissions <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = structure(c(16436, 
16443, 16574, 16468, 16481, 16494), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", 
"date"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> admissions
  id       date
1  1 2015-01-01
2  1 2015-01-08
3  1 2015-05-19
4  2 2015-02-02
5  2 2015-02-15
6  2 2015-02-28




events <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L), date = structure(c(16453, 
16578, 16467), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", "date"), row.names = 7:9, class = "data.frame")

> events
  id       date
7  1 2015-01-18
8  1 2015-05-23
9  2 2015-02-01
```

I guess I just need the minimum difference in days (only positive values considered) for each event relative to the admissions, matched within patients.

```
Event 1 (id ==1): +10 days (10 days after 08/01/2015)
Event 2 (id ==1): +4 days
Event 3 (id ==2): -1 days
```

I can then select those events that fall within my window (which will probably be 5 days).

My guess would be that lapply() is involved, but for some reason the apply's are not every natural to me (yet!).

Comment: It is not clear to me how you intend to compare the dates and id because they are of different lengths.

Comment: that's where the idea of a join comes in...

Comment: Date of event 1 should be compared with all 3 admission dates of patient 1, and the minimum (positive) times pan should be selected. Same for event 2 of patient 1, etc, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(events, event_id=row_number()) %>% # Add event id
    right_join(admissions, by="id") %>% # Join with admissions
    rename(adm_date = date.y, ev_date = date.x) %>% # Clean names
    mutate(diff = ev_date - adm_date) %>% # Compute diffrence
    filter(diff >= 0) %>% # Filter 
    group_by(event_id) %>%
    arrange(diff) %>% # Sort ascending by diff by event_id
    summarise_each(funs(first), ev_date, adm_date, diff) # Get nearest

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

  event_id    ev_date   adm_date    diff
1        1 2015-01-18 2015-01-08 10 days
2        2 2015-05-23 2015-05-19  4 days
```

Using `data.table` rolling join:

```
keycols <- c("id", "date")

admissions_dt <- admissions %>% mutate(adm_date = date) %>% as.data.table()
setkeyv(admissions_dt, keycols)

events_dt <- mutate(events, event_id=row_number()) %>% as.data.table()
setkeyv(events_dt, keycols)

admissions_dt[events_dt, roll=10][order(event_id)]

   id       date   adm_date event_id
1:  1 2015-01-18 2015-01-08        1
2:  1 2015-05-23 2015-05-19        2
3:  2 2015-02-01       <NA>        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table 1.9.5` for its `on=` feature.

1. For each row in `event`, find the index corresponding to the closest date <= `admissions$date`.

   ```
   idx = setDT(admissions)[events, which=TRUE, roll=TRUE, on=c("id", "date")]
   idx
   # [1]  2  3 NA
   ```

   If you already know you'll only prefer 5 day window, then you can use `roll=5` instead of `roll=TRUE`. `roll=<positive number>` performs a LOCF rolling join.
2. The indices correspond to matching rows in `admission` for each row of `event`. So we can now extract the date as follows:

   ```
   setDT(events)[, adm_date := admission$date[idx]]
   #    id       date   adm_date
   # 1:  1 2015-01-18 2015-01-08
   # 2:  1 2015-05-23 2015-05-19
   # 3:  2 2015-02-01       <NA>
   ```